# Bulk adding records to one table and using their auto-ids in a relation table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm building an application that generates forms, however since these forms can have 100's of fields on them I would like to create them in a few queries as possible. I have no issues against using stored procedures or functions.

## Forms

id - auto_inc
...

## Fields

id - auto_inc
...

## FormFields

formID - foreign key
fieldID - foreign key

When I create a form I run

```
INSERT INTO forms (xx) VALUES ('xx')
```

and then use

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

to get the ID from the form

Next I would like to add all the fields and their formfields relation in one or two queries.

```
INSERT INTO fields (xx, xx) VALUES ('xx', 'xx'), ('xx', 'xx'), ('xx', 'xx')...

Insert INTO formfields (formID, fieldID) 
VALUES (@FORM_ID, @fieldID1), (@FORM_ID @fieldID2)...
```

I'm using php to generate these queries dynamically so @FORM_ID would actually be a php variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use a combination of [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), here's an example

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    I CHAR(1)
)

CREATE TABLE Bar (
    PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    J INT
)

CREATE TABLE Map (
    FooPK INT,
    BarPK INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO Foo(I) VALUES ('A')

DECLARE @FooPK INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

DECLARE @temp TABLE (BarPK INT)

INSERT INTO Bar(J)
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK INTO @temp
VALUES (4), (5),(6),(7)

INSERT INTO Map(FooPK, BarPK)
SELECT @FooPK, BarPK
FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM Foo
SELECT * FROM Bar
SELECT * FROM Map
     GO

DROP TABLE Foo
DROP TABLE Bar
DROP TABLE Map
     GO
```

Comment: Tried it out one some temp tables and it works great, thank you for the help!